# printing uid of a file on linux system

Tags: c, linux

i am learning c programming. I am trying to make my own program similar to **ls** command but with less options.what i am doing is taking input directory/file name as argument and then gets all directory entry with **dirent** struct(if it is directory) .

After it i use stat() to take all information of the file but here is my problem when i use write() to print these value its fine but when i want to print these  with printf() i get warninng :  format ‘%ld’ expects type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__uid_t’. I don't know what should use at place of **%ld** and also for other special data types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no format specifier for `__uid_t`, because this type is system-specific and is not the part of C standard, and hence `printf` is not aware of it.

The usual workaround is to promote it to a type that would fit the entire range of UID values on all the systems you are targeting:

```
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long int)uid); /* some systems support 32-bit UIDs */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cast it to a long int:

```
printf("foobar: %ld\n", (long int)your_uid_t_variable);
```