# Is the uid_t type signed or unsigned?

Tags: c, uid

I know that the standard doesn't say anything about the signedness of `uid_t` or `gid_t`.

#### Inconsistency:

Page http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reading-Persona.html says:

> In the GNU C Library, this is an alias for **unsigned int**.

But `man setreuid` says:

> Supplying a value of **-1** for either the real or effective user ID forces the system to leave that ID unchanged.

#### Questions:

1. So, is `uid_t` signed or unsigned in the GNU Library?
2. How can I supply `-1` if `uid_t` and `gid_t` are unsigned (`-1` will be converted to `0xFFFFFFFF`)?

Comment: Not the same question, but yours is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984258/printing-uid-of-a-file-on-linux-system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uid_t` is (after some typedefs/defines) defined as `__U32_TYPE` which is defined as `unsigned int` (that is on my Gentoo Linux system).

However, just because `-1` has a special meaning it does not mean that UIDs are restricted to the numbers that fit in a signed `int`. It just means that the highest value (i.e. `(unsigned int)-1`) is not a valid UID. The code in `setreuid` probably uses the reverse form of that cast (`(signed int)ruid`) to compare against `-1` cleanly although it accepts an `uid_t`.

Comment: `uid_t` is a typedef of `__uid_t`, which is system specific because non-standard.

Comment: Correct, I followed the chain of typedefs/defines up a bit more.

Comment: But he might be on a different system, and have different typedefs and defines. Also, I'm too lazy to find what mine is :P

Answer (score 12):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) says explicitly that `pid_t` is a signed integer type used for representing process and process group IDs.

It says that `ino_t` is an unsigned integer type used for file serial numbers.

For both `uid_t` and `gid_t`, it says that the type is an integer type (no mention of signed or unsigned) used for user IDs and group IDS.

Thus, the standard clearly states that the type of `uid_t` and `gid_t` can be signed or unsigned depending on the platform. It is very reasonable to suppose that this indeterminacy arose because actual implementations used both signed and unsigned types, and the standard was designed not to invalidate existing implementations.

Comment: Could `int` just be assumed to be signed by default unless defined otherwise? From using `c99` and `c11`, I noticed the compiler would complain whenever using any other value (I usually try to use strict guidelines when compiling).

Comment: @jargonjunkie: `int` is 'always' a signed type — unless you're mucking around with bit-fields, it is *always* a signed type.  But I'm not sure how that's germane to the Q&A, so I suspect I'm missing what you're trying to ask.

Comment: According to your answer and source, it's defined as an integer which in C is an `int`. It's default is to assume a `signed` value. You could explicitly declare it as `signed int` or `unsigned int` as superfluous as it may be. Other than bit-fields, I can't think of another instance in which it would be affected. It was more a matter of explicit clarity; aside from being implied. If `uid_t` is an integer value, than it would make sense that it would be an `int` and not `unsigned int` unless `typedef` or `define` defined/aliased it as another "type" or value.

Comment: When I use "strict" options in `gcc` and compare `int` to `unsigned`, the compiler usually complains about the comparison. To me, this further implies that `uid_t` is type `int`. So when it's defined in the header as `uid_t` it's defined as something. I haven't looked at the source, but that's what I'm assuming.

Comment: You appear to misunderstand the term 'an integer type'. There's a difference between `int`, 'a signed integer type', 'an unsigned integer type', and 'an integer type'.  While `int` is an integer type, it is very far being the only integer type.  Some integer types are signed (and `int` is one such integer type); some integer types are unsigned (but `int` is not one of those integer types).  When the standards use the term 'an integer type', it means 'some integer type that might be signed or unsigned' (but it explicitly excludes floating point types, or arrays or structures or pointers, etc.).